# Help for improving my network

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have written the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

[place/.style={circle,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm},transition/.style={rectangle,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4mm}]

\node[place]      (c1)      at (-3,6)  {};
\node[place]      (c2)      at (0,6)   {};
\node[place]      (c3)      at (0,3)   {};
\node[place]      (c4)      at (1.5,2)   {};
\node[place]      (c5)      at (-1.5,2)   {};
\node[place]      (c6)      at (0,0)   {};
\node[place]      (c7)      at (-3,1)  {};
\node[place]      (c8)      at (2,1)  {};
\node[place]      (c9)      at (-2,0) {};
\node[place]      (c10)     at (-2,-4) {};
\node[place]      (c11)     at (-2,-8) {};
\node[place]      (c12)     at (2,-4)  {};
\node[place]      (c13)     at (2,-8)  {};
\node[transition] (r1)      at (-1,1)  {};
\node[transition] (r2)      at (1,1)  {};
\node[transition] (r3)      at (1,4.5)  {};
\node[transition] (r4)      at (-1,4.5)  {};
\node[transition] (r5)      at (-3,4.5)  {};
\node[transition] (r6)      at (-3,2)  {};
\node[transition] (r7)      at (-1,-2)  {};
\node[transition] (r8)      at (-2,-6) {};
\node[transition] (r9)      at (1,-2)  {};
\node[transition] (r10)     at (2,-6)  {};

\draw [->,thick] (c11) to (r8);
\draw [->,thick] (c10) to (r8);
\draw [->,thick] (c12) to (r10);
\draw [->,thick] (c13) to (r10);
\draw [->,thick] (r8)  to [bend right=45] (c10);
\draw [->,thick] (r10)  to [bend left=45] (c12);
\draw [->,thick] (r7) to (c10);
\draw [->,thick] (r9) to (c12);
\draw [->,thick] (c6) to (r7);
\draw [->,thick] (c6) to (r9);
\draw [->,thick] (c1) to (r5);
\draw [->,thick] (r5) to (c3);
\draw [->,thick] (r4) to (c3);
\draw [->,thick] (c3) to (r3);
\draw [->,thick] (r3) to (c2);
\draw [->,thick] (c2) to (r4);
\draw [->,thick] (c3) to (r1);
\draw [->,thick] (c3) to (r2);
\draw [->,thick] (r1) to (c6);
\draw [->,thick] (r2) to (c6);
\draw [->,thick] (c9) to [bend right=45] (r7);
\draw [->,thick] (r7) to [bend right=45] (c9);
\draw [->,thick] (c7) to (r6);
\draw [->,thick] (r6) to [bend right=45] (c5);
\draw [->,thick] (c5) to [bend right=45] (r6);
\draw [->,thick] (c7) to [bend right=45] (r1);
\draw [->,thick] (r1) to [bend right=45] (c7);
\draw [->,thick] (r2) to [bend right=45] (c8);
\draw [->,thick] (c8) to [bend right=45] (r2);
\draw [->,thick] (c4) to [bend right=45] (r2);
\draw [->,thick] (r2) to [bend right=45] (c4);
\draw [->,thick] (r1) to (c5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

How can I improve it in this way:

To make the color and size of circles, the tip of arrows, and the shape and color of rectangles like the ones in following picture (I don't need all rectangles to be vertical, some to be vertical and some horizontal):

[image]

Comment: See [Example: A Petri-net for Hagen](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/nodetutorial/). It uses `\usetikzlibrary{petri}` for tokens etc.

Comment: You could find answers to all these questions by searching for them sepeartely, e.g. you already use `minimum size=6mm` to set the size, change color with `draw=<color>` or `fill=<color>` etc.

Comment: Currently, your options are ignored, because of the empty line after `\begin{tikzpicture}`. If you remove it, it will work. As `place` and `transition` are already defined by `petri` there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some adaptations to answer your questions. Of course, you should fine tune the positioning again later.

#### Adaptations

- remove empty line before options of `tikzpicture`
- add `, minimum size=9mm, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20` to `place/.style`
- define `transitionh` (horizontal) and `transitionv` (vertical) and set `minimum width` and `minimum height` there
- change arrow tip with `>=latex`
- removed unused tikzlibraries: `decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit`
- you can insert a number of tokens, using `tokens=1` etc.

#### Recommendations

- I left `positioning` there, because I would recommend to use it for relative positioning instead of absolute.
- Have a look into [pgf/tikz manual](https://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) chapter 64 "Petri-Net Drawing Library" (there are some nice examples).

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    place/.style={circle, draw, thick, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=9mm, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20},
    transition/.style={rectangle, draw, thick, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm, fill=black},
    transitionh/.style={transition, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=3mm},
    transitionv/.style={transition, minimum height=8mm, minimum width=3mm},
    >=latex,
]

\node[place, tokens=1]      (c1)      at (-3,6)  {};
\node[place, tokens=2]      (c2)      at (0,6)   {};
\node[place]      (c3)      at (0,3)   {};
\node[place]      (c4)      at (1.5,2)   {};
\node[place]      (c5)      at (-1.5,2)   {};
\node[place]      (c6)      at (0,0)   {};
\node[place]      (c7)      at (-3,1)  {};
\node[place]      (c8)      at (2,1)  {};
\node[place]      (c9)      at (-2,0) {};
\node[place]      (c10)     at (-2,-4) {};
\node[place]      (c11)     at (-2,-8) {};
\node[place]      (c12)     at (2,-4)  {};
\node[place]      (c13)     at (2,-8)  {};
\node[transitionh] (r1)      at (-1,1)  {};
\node[transitionh] (r2)      at (1,1)  {};
\node[transitionh] (r3)      at (1,4.5)  {};
\node[transitionh] (r4)      at (-1,4.5)  {};
\node[transitionh] (r5)      at (-3,4.5)  {};
\node[transitionv] (r6)      at (-3,2)  {};
\node[transitionh] (r7)      at (-1,-2)  {};
\node[transitionh] (r8)      at (-2,-6) {};
\node[transitionh] (r9)      at (1,-2)  {};
\node[transitionh] (r10)     at (2,-6)  {};

\draw [->,thick] (c11) to (r8);
\draw [->,thick] (c10) to (r8);
\draw [->,thick] (c12) to (r10);
\draw [->,thick] (c13) to (r10);
\draw [->,thick] (r8)  to [bend right=45] (c10);
\draw [->,thick] (r10)  to [bend left=45] (c12);
\draw [->,thick] (r7) to (c10);
\draw [->,thick] (r9) to (c12);
\draw [->,thick] (c6) to (r7);
\draw [->,thick] (c6) to (r9);
\draw [->,thick] (c1) to (r5);
\draw [->,thick] (r5) to (c3);
\draw [->,thick] (r4) to (c3);
\draw [->,thick] (c3) to (r3);
\draw [->,thick] (r3) to (c2);
\draw [->,thick] (c2) to (r4);
\draw [->,thick] (c3) to (r1);
\draw [->,thick] (c3) to (r2);
\draw [->,thick] (r1) to (c6);
\draw [->,thick] (r2) to (c6);
\draw [->,thick] (c9) to [bend right=45] (r7);
\draw [->,thick] (r7) to [bend right=45] (c9);
\draw [->,thick] (c7) to (r6);
\draw [->,thick] (r6) to [bend right=45] (c5);
\draw [->,thick] (c5) to [bend right=45] (r6);
\draw [->,thick] (c7) to [bend right=45] (r1);
\draw [->,thick] (r1) to [bend right=45] (c7);
\draw [->,thick] (r2) to [bend right=45] (c8);
\draw [->,thick] (c8) to [bend right=45] (r2);
\draw [->,thick] (c4) to [bend right=45] (r2);
\draw [->,thick] (r2) to [bend right=45] (c4);
\draw [->,thick] (r1) to (c5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That wasn't in the code, so I updated the image (was just for testing). Put text into the `{}` to show it in the node. Use `label=right:$c_3$` (as option of a node) to put text next to a node. This is also shown in the linked manual chapter.

Comment: If you had looked into the linked chapter, you knew the answer to your first questions. You can also search for the other questions there first, then go to se and if there is nothing there, ask a new question.